# Installing monogame Visual Studio 2022 issues

Tags: monogame, failed-installation

When I try to install the Monogame extension into Visual Studio 2022, it straight up does not show with the right extension.
it is not listed on the extension list:
[(image of list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo3eA.png)

i have the .NET framework installed into visual studio, (but I did that after installing the actual vs program)
does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: However this github issue suggests that the extension is not compatible with VS2022: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/7669

Comment: yes, it does look like that it is not compatible with VS2022, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

MonoGame 3.8.1 is out and is compatible with Visual Studio 2022!

https://community.monogame.net/t/monogame-3-8-1/17786

Answer (score 0):

The extension install does seem broken. If you experience the no templates issue when using the extension as detailed in the installation guide, uninstall the extension, and then install it from the Package Manager Console by entering: “dotnet new install MonoGame.Templates.CSharp” into the command line. This will just download the templates directly.

If you have never used the Package Manager Console, open it from the Visual Studio menu bar by clicking, Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.